# Sign In Manager CheckPasswordSignInAsync fails

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Update #1: I've created a minimal reproducible example [here](https://github.com/adam-bentley/WebApplication1)**

I have a dotnet core 6 web API. I am using Microsoft Identity for authentication and authorization with a custom user & role store. When I call `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` on my sign-in manager, it fails with two error logs:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[0]
> Invalid password for user.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUPxw.png)
> User failed to provide the correct password.

The app initially used identity with EF Core and this did work, however, since refactoring to use custom stores it no longer works.

I'm confident that the password is correct since I used the signing manager itself to create the password hash. The only thing I can think of is an issue with the user store since that's what's changed since moving away from EF Core.

[image]

I have tried to enable debugging for the `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` method, but it fails for the `PreSignInCheck` result not being null, even though I can see the variable's value is null. It also hits a logger call further down which wouldn't happen if the `PreSignInCheck` didn't fail.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

**Full Code**

**Application User**

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public short Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string NormalizedUsername { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Login endpoint**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDto.Email);

    if (user == null) 
        return Unauthorized();

    SignInResult result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDto.Password, false);
    return result.Succeeded ? await CreateUserObject(user) : Unauthorized();
}
```

**Custom userstore**

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public UserStore(IOptions<ConnectionOptions> connectionOptions)
    {
        _connectionString = spacestationDBOptions.Value.DefaultConnection;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, normalized_email, email_confirmed,  normalized_username, username, password) VALUES
                        (@firstname, @lastname, @email, @normalized_email, @email_confirmed, @normalized_username, @username, @password) RETURNING ID;";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", user.FirstName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", user.LastName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", user.Email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("normalized_email", user.NormalizedEmail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email_confirmed", user.EmailConfirmed);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", user.Email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("normalized_username", user.NormalizedEmail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", user.Password);
            user.Id = Convert.ToInt16(await command.ExecuteScalarAsync(cancellationToken));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed();
        }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"DELETE FROM users WHERE id = @id";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", user.Id);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed();
        }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    public void Dispose() => GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, normalized_email, email_confirmed, password, username, normalized_username FROM users WHERE normalized_email = @email;";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", normalizedEmail);
            using NpgsqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                return new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt16(0),
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                    Email = reader.GetString(3),
                    NormalizedEmail = reader.GetString(4),
                    EmailConfirmed = reader.GetBoolean(5),
                    Password = reader.GetString(6),
                    Username = reader.GetString(7),
                    NormalizedUsername = reader.GetString(8),
                };

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, normalized_email, email_confirmed, password, username, normalized_username FROM users WHERE id = @id;";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", userId);
            using NpgsqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                return new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt16(0),
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                    Email = reader.GetString(3),
                    NormalizedEmail = reader.GetString(4),
                    EmailConfirmed = reader.GetBoolean(5),
                    Password = reader.GetString(6),
                    Username = reader.GetString(7),
                    NormalizedUsername = reader.GetString(8),
                };

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, normalized_email, email_confirmed, password, username, normalized_username FROM users WHERE normalized_email = @normalized_email;";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("normalized_email", normalizedUserName);
            using NpgsqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                return new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt16(0),
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                    Email = reader.GetString(3),
                    NormalizedEmail = reader.GetString(4),
                    EmailConfirmed = reader.GetBoolean(5),
                    Password = reader.GetString(6),
                    Username = reader.GetString(7),
                    NormalizedUsername = reader.GetString(8),
                };

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Task<string> GetEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Email);
    }

    public Task<bool> GetEmailConfirmedAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.EmailConfirmed);
    }

    public Task<string> GetNormalizedEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.NormalizedEmail);
    }

    public Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.NormalizedUsername);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Password);
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Id.ToString());
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Username);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Password != null);
    }

    public Task SetEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user, string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.Email = email;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetEmailConfirmedAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.EmailConfirmed = confirmed;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetNormalizedEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user, string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.NormalizedEmail = normalizedEmail;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.NormalizedUsername = normalizedName;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(ApplicationUser user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.Password = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.Username = userName;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sql = @"UPDATE users SET firstname=@firstname, lastname=@lastname, email=@email, normalized_email=@normalized_email, email_confirmed=@email_confirmed, password=@password WHERE ID=@id;";
        try
        {
            using NpgsqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            NpgsqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", user.FirstName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", user.LastName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", user.Email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("normalized_email", user.NormalizedEmail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email_confirmed", user.EmailConfirmed);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", user.Password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", user.Id);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed();
        }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is somewhere here in the sign-in manager, where success is being set to false (User-manager code).

```
public virtual async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TUser user, string password)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var passwordStore = GetPasswordStore();
    if (user == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var result = await VerifyPasswordAsync(passwordStore, user, password);
    if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded)
    {
        await UpdatePasswordHash(passwordStore, user, password, validatePassword: false);
        await UpdateUserAsync(user);
    }

   var success = result != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
   if (!success)
   {
       Logger.LogWarning(LoggerEventIds.InvalidPassword, "Invalid password for user.");
   }
   return success;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adam, did you check the details of the fail error message? From your repo, you seem do not register and use the database? Custom UserStore just provides the methods for all data operations on the user.

Comment: Hi, I am registering the stores, you can see it in the program.cs of the example repo. I think it has something to do with the username being set as an email which causes a validation error. I'm just doing further research before I post it as an answer.

Thanks, Adam